# Sort JSON arrays within a JSON array, with a custom order in PHP

Tags: php, json, sorting, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to sort the array below, by id with a custom order, preferably by creating an array `(2177,1073,2951)`. I've attempted to use various PHP functions, but can't figure out how to specify a custom order. The data is returned via an API in a random order, and I need it sorted so I can use it.

```
{
    "data": {
        "people": [
            {
                "id": "1073",
                "name": "rob",
            },
            {
                "id": "2951",
                "name": "cam",
            },
            {
                "id": "2177",
                "name": "mike",
            }
        ]

    }
}
```

I want to turn the above into this:

```
{
    "data": {
        "people": [
            {
                "id": "2177",
                "name": "mike",
            },
            {
                "id": "1073",
                "name": "rob",
            },
            {
                "id": "2951",
                "name": "cam",
            }
        ]

    }
}
```

Comment: Give them a custom order ID, "1, 2, 3" etc..  and then order by that ID.

Comment: How are you ordering these? totally custom? They don't seem to be alphabetical, or numerically descending or ascending..

Comment: Planning to order them with a custom order, (2177,1073,2951).

Comment: well, the issue really isn't about what function you need to use, maybe start working first, on how to do your custom sorting